# Cleanly overide pip package for development

Tags: django, python-3.x, pip

I have a django project I am working on that requires a fairly simple pip package.

I have found a bug in that pip package.

I want to pull the source locally, write some fixes myself, and temporarily have my django project reference the local changes instead of the pip package.

What is the cleanest way to do this? Ideally, I would be able to accomplish this with an environment change or a small django configuration change, so that when my patch gets pulled into a release I can easily revert back to using the pip package.

Answer (score 0):

You should fork the project. Often these days projects are hosted on Github; fork the repo there, make your changes and push them to your forked repo. Then you can refer to your forked version [in your requirements.txt file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/?highlight=requirements.txt#requirements-files).

Comment: I want to work on changes and test them locally in my project, so ideally that wouldn't require me to push changes to github & run pip install every time I change a file.

Of course, once I have my changes done and I push my changes to the rest of the team / environments, I will be doing this. But it is cumbersome while I am developing my fix.

Comment: You can use `pip install -e` to install an [editable version](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs) for local development.

Comment: Ah! Yes, `-e` is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Also, once you fixed the bug, make a pull request back to the original repo so that we can all reap the benefits from your nice work.